# Do we need to load the Permission again and again if we have More than 1 module in Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my case I have multiples Modules in App, I do load the permission on very initial stage after login response which is part of root module. it loads successfully on root modules but when I jump for module B or C and try to get the same loaded permission on Module B,C components I'm getting null. any idea?

Loading permissions:

const permissions = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
NgxPermissionsService.loadPermissions(permissions)

get permission:
let roles[] = this.permissionsService.getPermissions()

Answer (score 1):

The `NgxPermissionsModule` should only be imported from one module in your application, otherwise you will end up with multiple instances of services imported by the module. Make sure you have a single shared module which can then be imported by your different modules. This shared module would import the `NgxPermissionsModule`. If you do this you only need to load permissions once.